# JPA Criteria API - How to get the opposite side of a unidirectional ManyToOne relationship from JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here is how my data looks:

```
@Entity
public class Pet {
  @Id
  protected Long id;
  protected String name;
  protected String color;
}

@Entity
public class Owner {
  @Id
  protected Long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pet_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  protected Pets pets;
}
```

If I start with `Pet`, how can I join to the owner.  I am trying to create this query:

```
SELECT * FROM pet p
  INNER JOIN owner o ON p.id = o.pet_id;
```

I don't want to add a new annotation to my `Pet`.  I can start with a `criteriaBuilder`, here is what I tried

```
Root<Pet> pet = query.from(Pet.class);
Join<Pet, Owner> owners = pet.join("pet_id");
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: Define a _NamedQuery_ in your Pet entity and map it to a method in your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Good approach but you've got things a bit turned around. Many pets belong to one owner.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Owner {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Pet {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    @ManyToOne
    // this is redundant
    // @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Owner owner;

}
```

And the most obvious way to use them is like so:

```
tx.begin();
Owner o = new Owner();
o.setId(1L);
em.persist(o);
Pet p1 = new Pet();
p1.setId(1L);
p1.setName("Tom");
p1.setColor("Black and White");
p1.setOwner(o);
em.persist(p1);
Pet p2 = new Pet();
p2.setId(2L);
p2.setName("Jerry");
p2.setColor("Grey");
p2.setOwner(o);
em.persist(p2);
tx.commit();

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.select(pet).where(cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.owner), 1L));
List<Pet> pets= em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets);
List<Pet> pets2 = em.createQuery("select p from Pet p where p.owner.id = :ownerId", Pet.class).setParameter("ownerId", 1L).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets2);
```

or

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.select(pet).where(cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.owner), o));
List<Pet> pets= em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets);
List<Pet> pets2 = em.createQuery("select p from Pet p where p.owner = :owner", Pet.class).setParameter("owner", o).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets2);
```

and get from the logs:

```
Hibernate: create table Owner (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Pet (id bigint not null, color varchar(255), name varchar(255), owner_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table Pet add constraint FKlvivrebsqkfp4s4svpd18dqmv foreign key (owner_id) references Owner
Hibernate: insert into Owner (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Pet (color, name, owner_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Pet (color, name, owner_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select pet0_.id as id1_1_, pet0_.color as color2_1_, pet0_.name as name3_1_, pet0_.owner_id as owner_id4_1_ from Pet pet0_ where pet0_.owner_id=1
[Pet(id=1, name=Tom, color=Black and White, owner=Owner(id=1)), Pet(id=2, name=Jerry, color=Grey, owner=Owner(id=1))]
Hibernate: select pet0_.id as id1_1_, pet0_.color as color2_1_, pet0_.name as name3_1_, pet0_.owner_id as owner_id4_1_ from Pet pet0_ where pet0_.owner_id=?
[Pet(id=1, name=Tom, color=Black and White, owner=Owner(id=1)), Pet(id=2, name=Jerry, color=Grey, owner=Owner(id=1))]
```

You can also get the opposite side of a unidirectional `ManyToOne` relationship from JPA like so:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Owner> cq = cb.createQuery(Owner.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.select(pet.get(Pet_.owner)).where(cb.equal(pet, p1));
Owner o1  = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
System.out.println(o1);
Owner o2 = em.createQuery("select p.owner from Pet p where p = :pet", Owner.class).setParameter("pet", p1).getSingleResult();
System.out.println(o2);
```

and get from the logs:

```
Hibernate: select owner1_.id as id1_0_ from Pet pet0_ inner join Owner owner1_ on pet0_.owner_id=owner1_.id where pet0_.id=?
Owner(id=1)
Hibernate: select owner1_.id as id1_0_ from Pet pet0_ inner join Owner owner1_ on pet0_.owner_id=owner1_.id where pet0_.id=?
Owner(id=1)
```

Of course, you may not want to use a `where` clause, so you can do:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Owner> cq = cb.createQuery(Owner.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.select(pet.get(Pet_.owner));
List<Owner> o1s  = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
System.out.println(o1s);
List<Owner> o2s = em.createQuery("select p.owner from Pet p", Owner.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(o2s);
```

or, to get to what you specifically asked for:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
pet.join(Pet_.owner);
cq.select(pet);
List<Pet> pets= em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets);
List<Pet> pets2 = em.createQuery("select p from Pet p join p.owner", Pet.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets2);
```

and the logs will be, respectively:

```
Hibernate: select owner1_.id as id1_0_ from Pet pet0_ inner join Owner owner1_ on pet0_.owner_id=owner1_.id
[Owner(id=1), Owner(id=1)]
Hibernate: select owner1_.id as id1_0_ from Pet pet0_ inner join Owner owner1_ on pet0_.owner_id=owner1_.id
[Owner(id=1), Owner(id=1)]
Hibernate: select pet0_.id as id1_1_, pet0_.color as color2_1_, pet0_.name as name3_1_, pet0_.owner_id as owner_id4_1_ from Pet pet0_ inner join Owner owner1_ on pet0_.owner_id=owner1_.id
[Pet(id=1, name=Tom, color=Black and White, owner=Owner(id=1)), Pet(id=2, name=Jerry, color=Grey, owner=Owner(id=1))]
Hibernate: select pet0_.id as id1_1_, pet0_.color as color2_1_, pet0_.name as name3_1_, pet0_.owner_id as owner_id4_1_ from Pet pet0_ inner join Owner owner1_ on pet0_.owner_id=owner1_.id
[Pet(id=1, name=Tom, color=Black and White, owner=Owner(id=1)), Pet(id=2, name=Jerry, color=Grey, owner=Owner(id=1))]
```

Which are the JPA equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM pet p
  INNER JOIN owner o ON p.id = o.pet_id;
```

With the `foreign key` on the `pet` table instead of the `owner` table as pointed out at the beginning.

Keep in mind that you don't need to expressly do a join because JPA will automatically get the other side of a `ManyToOne` relationship anyway. For example:

```
// start fresh
em.clear();
//
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.select(pet);
List<Pet> pets= em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets);
List<Pet> pets2 = em.createQuery("select p from Pet p", Pet.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(pets2);
```

will give you

```
Hibernate: select pet0_.id as id1_1_, pet0_.color as color2_1_, pet0_.name as name3_1_, pet0_.owner_id as owner_id4_1_ from Pet pet0_
Hibernate: select owner0_.id as id1_0_0_ from Owner owner0_ where owner0_.id=?
[Pet(id=1, name=Tom, color=Black and White, owner=Owner(id=1)), Pet(id=2, name=Jerry, color=Grey, owner=Owner(id=1))]
Hibernate: select pet0_.id as id1_1_, pet0_.color as color2_1_, pet0_.name as name3_1_, pet0_.owner_id as owner_id4_1_ from Pet pet0_
[Pet(id=1, name=Tom, color=Black and White, owner=Owner(id=1)), Pet(id=2, name=Jerry, color=Grey, owner=Owner(id=1))]
```

which is the equivalent query done using two queries and caching instead of always using one query with an inner join so that repeat queries are more efficient.